# How to reproduce a figure of a paper in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing

I have the following figure:

[image]

I'd like to reproduce it in Mathematica. It's doable to read the positions of the points by eye and then plot them; but, is there a more precise way of doing it?

Comment: `ListLinePlot` with `ColorFunction`

Comment: Oops, didn't realize that my single close vote would result in immediately closing this question. Anyway, you should take a look at that other question first, and if that's insufficient for a solution, ask specifically about issues not already covered in the answers there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must first get the coordinates of the points. Toward this aim, enlarge the picture a bit, copy it and paste it into Mathematica. Then right click into the picture and choose "Get Coordinates". Now read the coordinates of the lower left point and store it in: cll. The same for the upper right point: cur. Now define the values of these points as: ll and ur (you may do this more precise):

```
cll = {48.5, 40};
cur = {332.5, 303};
ll = {5, 2};
ur = {30, 100};
```

Now read the coordinates of all the points. Out of laziness, I do it only for moi500:

```
 cmoi500 = {{49, 217.8}, {106, 291}, {162, 303}, {218.5, 303}, {275.5, 
    303}, {332.5, 303}};
```

Next we transform the coordinate values to real values by:

```
moi500 = ( # - cll)/ (cur - cll) (ur - ll) + ll & /@ cmoi500 // N
```

Now we can plot the data (to beatify the plot use more option of ListLinePlot);

```
ListLinePlot[moi500, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that your coordinate values will be different as they depend on the magnification.

Comment: I took the point that is lowest at x==5. I guessed it to be a little over zero, that is 2.