# Recovering data points and reproducing a figure

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing

Yesterday, I asked a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275087/how-to-reproduce-a-figure-of-a-paper-in-mathematica), that how can one read off the coordinates of the points and reproduce a published plot. Daniel Huber provided an immensely helpful answer and I could reproduce the whole figure with his approach. However, it seems it doesn't work for the following figure:

[image]

I guess the $x$-axis of the above plot is scaled by $\log2$. How can I modify Daniel Huber's answer to be also applicable to this case?

Comment: Scale x-coords by the function `InverseFunction[Log2]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of laziness I only treat one curve.

We take only the y value from the "GetCoordinate" function. The x values we take from the plot. This gives for the lower left and upper right point: ll, ur and the data following values:

```
cll = {4, 27};
cur = {500, 169};
cdat = {{4, 27}, {8, 30}, {16, 36}, {31, 50}, {63, 71}, {125, 
   102}, {250, 140}, {500, 169}}
```

This data we can use to get the original y values as before:

```
dat = (# - cll)/(cur - cll) (ur - ll) + ll & /@ cdat;
```

And finally we can again make a log-linear plot

```
ListLogLinearPlot[dat]
```

[image]

Unfortunately there is no "ListLineLogLinearPlot", we need to do it ourself.

```
logdat = {Log[2, #[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ dat;
ListLinePlot[logdat, 
 Ticks -> {{{2, 4 }, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8, 
     250}, {9, 500}}, Automatic}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]